# PanResponder not working properly on Android when Animated.View has an Animated.ScrollView as a child

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a an issue on Android with my pangesture.

I have an Animated.ScrollView inside my Animated.View. Whenever I drag my Animated.View slowly, it works perfectly but whenever I flick really quick, the Animated.View stops after a couple of pixels.

The bug doesn't happen when I disable the scroll on the Animated.ScrollView. My guess is that the Animated.ScrollView takes over when swiping too fast.

Anyone has an idea why this happens? This does not happen on iOS.

Detail View:

```
class DetailScreen extends PureComponent<Props> {
    state = {
        closeToTop: true,
        closeToBottom: false
    };

    scrollY = new Animated.Value(0);
    scrollView?: ScrollView;

    handleScroll = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
        const closeToTop = this.isCloseToTop(e);
        if (closeToTop !== this.state.closeToTop) {
            this.setState({ closeToTop });
        }

        const closeToBottom = this.isCloseToBottom(e);
        if (closeToBottom !== this.state.closeToBottom) {
            this.setState({ closeToBottom });
        }
    };

    isCloseToTop = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
        const { contentOffset } = e.nativeEvent;

        return contentOffset.y === 0;
    };

    isCloseToBottom = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
        const { layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize } = e.nativeEvent;
        return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >= contentSize.height - 20;
    };

    renderContent = () => {
        return (
            <Animated.ScrollView
                contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                scrollEventThrottle={16}
                bounces={false}
                // scrollEnabled={false}
                overScrollMode={"never"}
                onScroll={Animated.event(
                    [
                        {
                            nativeEvent: {
                                contentOffset: {
                                    y: this.scrollY
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    {
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        listener: this.handleScroll
                    }
                )}
                ref={(ref: any) => (this.scrollView = ref && ref.getNode())}>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                        <View style={{...styles.container, height: 200, backgroundColor: "red"}}>
                            <Text>red</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ ...styles.container, height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
                            <Text>yellow</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ ...styles.container, height: 200, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
                            <Text>green</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ ...styles.container, height: 200, backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
                            <Text>blue</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ ...styles.container, height: 200, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                            <Text>red</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ ...styles.container, height: 200, backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
                            <Text>yellow</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </Animated.ScrollView>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
                <SwipeableModal
                    onClose={this.props.navigation.pop}
                    nearTop={this.state.closeToTop}
                    nearBottom={this.state.closeToBottom}>
                    {this.renderContent()}
                </SwipeableModal>
        );
    }
 }
```

Swipeable Modal

```
const { height: screenHeight } = Dimensions.get("window");
const TIMING_CONFIG = { duration: 300, easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease) };

class SwipeableModal extends PureComponent<Props, State> {
    panResponder: PanResponderInstance;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pan: new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 }),
            isDragging: false
        };

        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            // Ask to be the responder:
            onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => false,
            onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => false,
            onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => false,

            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
                if (this.state.isDragging) {
                    return true;
                }

                // moving finger from top to bottom
                if (gestureState.vy > 0 && this.props.nearTop) {
                    this.setState({ isDragging: true });
                    return true;
                }

                // moving finger from bottom to top
                if (gestureState.vy < 0 && this.props.nearBottom) {
                    this.setState({ isDragging: true });
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            },
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: gestureState.dy });
            },
            onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
                this.setState({ isDragging: false });
                if (gestureState.vy <= -0.7 || gestureState.dy <= -300) {
                    // move from bottom to top
                    Animated.timing(this.state.pan, {
                        toValue: { x: 0, y: -screenHeight },
                        ...TIMING_CONFIG
                    }).start(this.closeModal);
                } else if (gestureState.vy >= 0.5 || gestureState.dy >= 300) {
                    // move from top to
                    Animated.timing(this.state.pan, {
                        toValue: { x: 0, y: screenHeight },
                        ...TIMING_CONFIG
                    }).start(this.closeModal);
                } else {
                    Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
                        toValue: 0
                    }).start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    closeModal = () => {
        this.props.onClose();
    };

    handleGetStyle() {
        return [
            style.container,
            {
                transform: [...this.state.pan.getTranslateTransform()]
            }
        ];
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View style={this.handleGetStyle()} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }
}
```

[Video example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY6Qf.jpg)
[Github project that reproduces the bug](https://github.com/VanHoutte/ReactNativeAndroidPanGestureBug/tree/master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I was able to fix this issue by reimplementing the swipe-able modal with react-native-gesture-handler.

If anyone needs help, let me know.